# I am extracting data from planner with power automate, however, the send an HTTP request is not pulling all tasks

Tags: power-automate, power-platform, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I am extracting data from planner with power automate, however, the send an HTTP request is not pulling all tasks. I have many tasks closs to 900 but when I run the flow the action "Send an HTTP request" is only etracting 400 tasks. I am using this as URI [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/{plan](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/%7Bplan) id}/tasks?$expand=details. I have tried different things I have found online but I have not really found anythings that works. I was thinking on probably something simple liek changing settings like one might do with using the get tasks details action and turn on pagination but for the action "Send an HTTP request" there is not such setting available. Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Also, I am not expert on this as you can probably tell by now, I am just learning as I go...

all tasks from planner not only 400

Comment: This is the generic info about pagination in the Graph API ... so you are not getting a "nextLink" value in your response?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: @odata.Nextlink will have the url for the next page (See the link in the above comment). Maybe you can share the relevant parts of your power automate job so people can help handling paging correctly.